# Replace " with &quote from varchar variable in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to replace `"` with `&quot`, `replace(@variable,'"','&quot;')` didn't help, in XML I got

```
<tag>&amp quot;Test&amp quot;</tag>
```

instead of

```
<tag>&quot;test&quot;</tag>
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @Text varchar(20) = '"Test"'
SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'"','&quot ;')
SELECT @Text
DECLARE @Table table (ID int)
INSERT INTO @Table
    (ID)
VALUES
    (123)
DECLARE @TestXml AS XML = ( 
    SELECT
        @Text
    FROM @Table AS tag  
    FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
    )   
SELECT @TestXml
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove this line -> `SET @Text = REPLACE(@Text,'"','&quot ;')` & try again.

Comment: if you remove the set @Text = replace.... the result will be "Test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the problem is in the select query, try below sql

change the

```
SELECT @TestXml
```

to

```
SELECT '<tag>' + @TestXml.value('/tag[1]','varchar(max)') + '</tag>'  as 'Word'
```

you will get below result in the select query:

```
Word
-------------------------------
<tag>&quot;Test&quot;</tag>
```

**Update**

to keep the '&' char we need  the <![CDATA[...]>
try below sql

```
Declare @text nvarchar(20) = '"Test"'
select @text = replace(@text,'"','&quot;')
Declare @table table (ID int)
Declare @xml as nvarchar(Max)

insert into @table values (123)

set @xml=( Select 
    1 as tag,
    Null as Parent,
    @text as [tag!1!!CDATA]
from @table 
for xml Explicit
)

select @xml
```

Result:

```
result
---------------------------------------
<tag><![CDATA[&quot;Test&quot;]]></tag>
```

Comment: the problem is that i have to insert into xml value from varchar and replace " with &quot and save it to the disk as xml

Comment: i have an update. it use <![CData[...]> to keep the special char.